# Regarding a difficulty in the Fakir article about associated idempotent triple

Tags: category-theory, monads

I just had post this question here but in a less exact form .

I understand that at the first sight it seems a silly/trivial verifications (to me too) but I discussed the matter with some known person (PhD) and my doubt seems to be well founded.

On the ncatlab work http://ncatlab.org/toddtrimble/published/Associated+idempotent+monad+of+a+monad  Todd Trimbe quote the Fakir theorem about the associated idempotent triple:

Let $(T, \eta  , \mu)$ a  triple on a complete category  $\mathscr{C}$ he define a triple $(T', \eta', \mu')$ as follow: let  $T'$ the Kernel:   $T' \xrightarrow{k_X} T \rightrightarrows T \circ T$ where the couple is given by $\eta  T$ and $T\eta $. From $\eta T \ast \eta  = T\eta \ast \eta $ (apply  $\eta$ to $\eta_X$)  follow $\eta': 1 \Rightarrow  T'$ with $\eta_X= k_X\circ  \eta'_X $. We observe that:

1)  $\mu_X \circ  T(\eta_X)= 1_{T(X)}$  and then $\mu_X\circ T(k_X)\circ T(\eta'_X)=1$ .

For obtain $\mu': T'T' \Rightarrow  T'$ we consider that  $T'T'(X)$ is defined as the follow Kernel:

$T'(T'(X)) \xrightarrow{k_{T'(X)}} T(T'(X)) \rightrightarrows (T \circ T)(T'(X))$ where the couple is given by
$\eta_{TT'X}$ and $T(\eta_{T'X}) $.

In the article [1] Fakir claim to obtain a morphism $\mu': T'T'(X) \to  T(X)$ from the universal property of kernel, assuming (implicitly) that $\mu_X\circ T(k_X)\circ k_{T'X}$ equalize the couple  $\eta_{TX},\ T\eta_X: T(X) \to T T(X)$, observe that from (1)  $\mu_X\circ T(k_X)$ cannot equalize this couple.

Then I consider the diagram

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
T'T'X & \xrightarrow{k_{T'X}} & TT'X & \xrightarrow[T\eta_{T'X}]{\eta_{TT'X}} & TTT'X \\
&& T(k_X)\downarrow && \downarrow TT(k_X)\\
& & TTX & \xrightarrow[T\eta_{TX}]{\eta_{TTX}} & TTTX \\
&& \mu_X\downarrow && \downarrow f\\
& & TX & \xrightarrow[T\eta_X]{\eta_{TX}} & TTX \\
\end{array}$$

If this is (mutually) commutative we are done. The top square is mutually commutative, but the below isn't if we put $f=T\mu$ or $f=\mu_T$.

How can we prove the existence of $\mu'$?

Biblio:

[1] Fakir, Monade idempotente associee a une monade, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Ser. A 270 (1970), 99-101